# Scala Spark groupBy/Agg functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I have two datasets that i need to join and perform operations on and I cant figure out how to do it.
A stipulation for this is that i do not have org.apache.spark.sql.functions methods available to me, so must use the dataset API

The input given is two Datasets
The first dataset is of type Customer with Fields:
customerId, forename, surname - All String

And the second dataset is of Transaction:
customerId (String), accountId(String), amount (Long)

customerId is the link

The outputted Dataset needs to have these fields:
customerId (String), forename(String), surname(String), transactions( A list of type Transaction), transactionCount (int), totalTransactionAmount (Double),averageTransactionAmount (Double)

I understand that i need to use groupBy, agg, and some kind of join at the end.
Can anyone help/point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Its very hard to help when you provide so little information, can you add some details like input, expected output. schema of dataframes?

Comment: why dont you have org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ available?

Comment: @werner It's a stipulation in the exercise that it cant be used, instead the Dataset API must be used

Comment: @koiralo Apologies, I have added the input/output types of fields, The input given is two datasets one is DataSet[Customer], other is Dataset[Transaction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to work with the information you have, but from what I understand you dont want to use the dataframe functions but implement everything with the dataset api, you could do this in the following way

1. Join both the datasets using joinWith, you can find an example here https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins.html#joinWith
2. Aggregating : I would use `groupByKey` followed by `mapGroups` something like

```
 ds.groupByKey(x=>x.id).mapGroups { case (key,iter) => { 
        val list = iter.toList
        val totalTransactionAmount = ???
        val averageTransactionAmount = ??? 
        (key,totalTransactionAmount,averageTransactionAmount)
   } 
 }
```

Hopefully the example gives you an idea how you could solve your problem with the dataset API and you could adapt it to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, This groupBy and mapGroups helped me to get the answer